# Opening files to edit in Nitrous IDE via CLI

Tags: ide, command-line-interface, nitrousio

I've been doing some testing with a Python box in Nitrous.IO, and I was looking for a way to open files via the CLI into the web based IDE.  This would be an alternative to going through the point & click menu on the left-hand side of the web IDE interface.

Does anyone know if Nitrous.IO has a CLI command that will open files into the web IDE?

Thank you,
SirCobalt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this right now. I've asked the question to Nitrous.IO, this was their reply:

> There isn't a way to open files into the editor from the console, but I'll bring this up with the team. Thanks for the feedback!